# Test a ManyToMany / OneToMany Association in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, spring-data-rest, junit5

Using, Spring Boot, Spring Data Rest and Hibernate
I have implemented 2 Entities

**Entity User**

```
public class User implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private UUID id;
 ...
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "toolUser", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tool"))
 private Set<Tool> tools;
 ...
}
```

**Entity Tool**

```
public class Tool implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private UUID id;
 ...
}
```

`@ManyToMany` is an unidirectional relationship

the 2 Repositories :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users", collectionResourceRel = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "tools", collectionResourceRel = "tools")
public interface ToolRepository extends JpaRepository<Tool, UUID> {
}
```

The integration test Class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DisplayName("User integration tests...")
public class UserIntegrationTest {
 ...
 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Autowired
 private WebApplicationContext wac;

 @BeforeEach
 public void setup() {
  mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
 }
 ...

 @Test
 @DisplayName("Post a correct user")public void WhenPostCorrectUser_thenCorrectStatusCodeAndResponse() throws Exception {
  User user = new User("firstName", "lastName");
  mockMvc.perform(post("http://localhost:8080/users").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user)))             
   .andExpect(status().isCreated());
 }

 ....
}
```

How to continue writing `@Test` for the association `@ManyToMany` that normally uses `text/uri-list` as request content type.